# Problem with require() when using a fully qualified URL

Tags: php

So, my code was using relative paths, but running into some problems with common files which could be include/required from different directory levels.

Absolute paths are more efficient anyway, right? So, I changed all include/require to absolute paths, using `require_once('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 'file_name.php');`

`$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` is correct, isn't it? It seemed so when I googled.

That required me to set 'allow_url_include=on` in php.ini and restart Apache.

So, now I have a situation that looks something like this (simplified example):

File2.php contains

```
<?php
   function hello()
   {
     echo 'hello<br>';
   }
?>
```

and if file1.php contains

```
<?php
   require_once('file2.php');    
   hello();
?>
```

then I see the expected output "hello", **but** if I change that line to

```
   require_once('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/file2.php');
```

Then I get "Fatal error: Call to undefined function hello() in C:\xampp\htdocs\file1.php"

(I guess that the reference to c:\xammp\httdos came from Xdebug, because PhpInfo shows HTTP_HOST    localhost)

Anyway, that's a long post to say that I am missing some simple point and to ask what it is.

Comment: I even did not read the whole question but requiring of remote files is always a bad idea.

Comment: btw, what do you get for `echo file_get_contents('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/file2.php');` ?

Comment: "requiring of remote files is always a bad idea" +1, but it's not really remote. It's on the same server ...  (if you still see that as 'remote' (and I could agree), what's your suggestion as to how to include with an absolute path? thanks)

Comment: @Mawg: what is the reason to include file with FQU, instead of local path?

Comment: To clarify for zerkms "Requiring of PHP source files via HTTP is a very bad idea if you want to process the delicious PHP goo inside"

Comment: +1 Ok, then I can try local path. Just thought I'd seen $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] recommended many places (including this site). Are you suggesting that I use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ?

Comment: @Mawg: not actually. The common practice is to define a constant with absolute path to your application's root and compose your paths based on that base-constant. I.e.: require_once BASE_PATH . 'path/to/concrete/file.php;`

Comment: +1 define the constant once per file? or in an include in a known location ;-)

Comment: @Mawg: that constant should be defined just once in some sort of "config"/"bootstrap"/"index" file, whatever you have and used in every other file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

require_once expects a path on the server and not a URL. So for example you can't pass http://www.foo.com/test.php but you can do /var/www/foo/test.php. If you put http:// path then it will only include the output and not the php functions.

Comment: +1 So, are you saying  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], rather than    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ?  Or something else? How do you include using an absolute path? Thanks

Comment: Correct, you can use DOCUMENT_ROOT. But if your files are sitting in www/test.php and you want to include other.php then just do require_once(other.php). This path is better as relative than absolute.

Comment: Just be careful where it's relative to. All relative paths in PHP are relative to the `include_path`. This may or may not include the CWD `.`

Comment: answer awarded for confirming  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']

Answer (score 8):

When you `require` a full URL, PHP makes a request to the server and gets back the **output** of the PHP script - this will not contain any actual PHP code (unless the script itself outputs PHP code).

Also, you aren't going to see any noticeable difference in performance between using relative and absolute paths, so don't worry too much about it. In fact, your path is not an absolute path but an absolute URI, and fetching a URI is actually going to be *way* slower than using local paths.

Comment: +1 you are correct. So. what's the correct way to include using an absolute path? Thanks

Comment: @Mawg: the correct way is to `include` your file, not `require`.

Comment: @Mawg: Use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/path/to/file'`.

Comment: @casablanca: huh? Where did you get that "It's good to require libraries and such, but include templates or other things that can be repeated within the same page" ?

Comment: @zerkms The difference is in how they handle errors. A failing `require` will throw a fatal error, halting all other execution. A failing `include` will throw a warning, however execution will continue.

Comment: @Phil Brown: i know what is the difference, but i cannot get why include is better for templates and require - for libraries. You **never** should try to include/require not-existent files. Each this attempt should raise an exception and your application should be halted.

Comment: @zerkms: Sorry, I confused `require_once` and `require` for a moment. So it should have been this way: you should almost always use `require` because if the file you're including doesn't exist, something is wrong with your script and it deserves to fail.

Comment: @casablanca: yup, excatly the same I think (and said) ;-)

Comment: @zerkms: But you said to use `include` and not `require`, while I suggest always using `require`.

Comment: @casablanca: `include` just as solition of require-issue-with-remote-files issue.

Answer (score 2):

Absolute means relative to the file system.  You're using url includes when you use `http://...`, but you're using normal includes when you use `file2.php`. To use real absolute paths use `require_once('/xampp/htdocs/file2.php');`.

Comment: +1 hut I don't want to use /xampp/htdocs/  (maybe $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] ? )

Comment: Set a known absolute path using `set_include_path()`. You can set it via configuration or determine it using something like `realpath(dirname(__FILE__))`

Comment: +1 I guess that would work, but it is slightly inefficient (and it's no longer clear from the code where to look for the include file when developing)

Comment: One common pattern is to use `require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/relative/path/to/file1.php')`. That ensures that no matter where you include a file from, its includes will still work.

Comment: @theazureshadow great short solution!

Answer (score 1):

When you `require` or `include` a file in PHP, the file is merged into the current script from the local filesystem unless the file path includes a schema such as HTTP, then it will be included by one of the fopen wrappers. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

PHP determines the full path to the file based on certain factors.

An absolute path (one beginning with a `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` (eg `/`) or drive letter identified (eg `C:\`) for Windows servers) is the quickest as there is no translation to do. The file is simply merged in from the given location.

A relative path however is much more complex than most imagine.

PHP will search for the relative path in the `include_path` stack (FIFO). This is a `PATH_SEPARATOR` (`;`) delimited string containing one or more "base" paths.

An example include path is

```
/usr/share/pear;.
```

This contains two paths, `/usr/share/pear` and `.`, the current working directory (CWD).

You will receive the best performance in your application if you specifically set your include path and remove anything not relevant. For example, say all your "includable" files reside in `/home/me/www/appname/includes`, your best bet is to set this in your bootstrap / common script, eg

```
set_include_path('/home/me/www/appname/includes');
```

Now any relative include call will only fetch from this location.

If you need to set multiple paths, I find something like this works well

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/include/path/one',
    '/include/path/two'
)));
```

and if you want to ammend the server include path, I'd advise to add it in the same way but place it at the bottom of the stack, eg

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    '/include/path/one',
    '/include/path/two',
    get_include_path()
)));
```

IMHO, one of the best things you can do is remove the CWD from the include path as it tends to be one of the biggest sources of "include path hell". If you do need to include a file relative to the current one, use

```
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/relative/path/to/file.php';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use file_get_contents function

```
file_get_contents('http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/file2.php');
```

But it is mainly useful for connecting to an external domain

Comment: Late to the party, but better late than never :-) Your answer may help someone, although I  accepted 12 years ago that I should not do this. ***Possibly*** during development, but it is not a great idea in production. Also, this method won't suppose the `_once` functionality of `require_once`. Upvote, though; this may well help someone. Thanks